# Pandas Dataframe NaN values replace by no values

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I wanted to replace the NaN value by an empty value to write it into an mysql database. I don't want to drop (`df.dropna()`) the the full row neither to replace it by 0 using `df.fillna(0)`. When using `df.fillna('')` or `df.fillna('NULL')` gives an error message:

> (mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 1265 (01000): Data truncated
>   for column 'log_return' at row

The data in the dataframe looks like the following:

```
          date     price     log_return                 
0   2017-02-14     105.800   -0.006125                          
1   2017-02-13     106.450   0.004236 
2   2017-02-10     106.000   NaN
```

What I want is the following:

```
          date     price     log_return                 
0   2017-02-14     105.800   -0.006125                          
1   2017-02-13     106.450   0.004236 
2   2017-02-10     106.000
```

Comment: how do you want the data represented in MYSQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

`df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)`

**example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.eye(3))
df = df.where(lambda x: x==1, np.nan)
df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)
```

Note that pd.fillna(None) will not work, it leaves the NaN values untouched.

source https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/1972

Comment: thanks a lot. Did not know that with ´None´ this is possible :).

Comment: I was surprised to learn that pd.fillna(None) doesn't work. That's discussed in the link, but since it fails quietly, and isn't directly mentioned in either the question or the answer, it might be helpful to add a note not to try it to the answer.